# Recursive Linked List Reverser

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

Created a linked list class for a java project and needed a method to reverse the list so my friend and I eventually came up with the following recursive method and it's helper method:

(just for clarification, `first` is the instance variable of the first node in the list)

```
public void reverse()
{
    first = reverse(first);
}

public Node reverse(Node in) 
{
    if (in == null || in.next == null) 
    {
         return in;
    }

         Node next = in.next;
         in.next = null;
         Node rest = reverse(next);
         next.next = in;
         return rest;
}
```

When the nodes contain integers and we input 1, 2, and 3 at the beginning of the list (they become 3, 2, 1 when added as the first node) and then try to reverse the 3, 2, 1 to become 1, 2, 3 the function works as planned.

My issue here is that I really am having trouble comprehending what is happening here.

For instance, when I trace the function (for 3, 2, 1) it appears that:

`next` = `in.next` (which is `2, 1`) gets passed down again until it is just `(1)` and then that gets passed back up into `rest`. But after the recursion takes place, nothing is actually happening to `rest`. It's happening to `next.next` and I cannot make out how `next.next` is affecting `rest` in any way.

I can't seem to locate the points in which `rest` goes from being `(1)` to `(1,2)` to `(1,2,3)` during the bubbling back up.

If anyone could help explain more in depth how this function is modifying `rest` that would be great. I have traced this function almost 20 or so times now trying to understand and something is taking place that I just can't seem to see.

I even took it to my teacher and he gave me some BS response equivalent to "If it works, then it works, it's recursion, don't try to understand it." -- What kind of advice is that??

Thanks

Comment: To be honest, this actually really is a very confusing implementation of reverse since it modifies the list.  That's always going to be harder to follow because nodes are being repurposed when it'd be more clear what's happening if you just created new nodes.  Most functional languages that operate on recursive/linked lists actually use immutable lists.

Comment: But in general if you're trying to understand the control flow of a piece of code, break out a piece of paper and a pencil and write down the values of each object/variable at each step of exectuion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try drawing a list with 2 nodes in it.  This is the simplest example.

```
first --> [A] -> [B] -> null
```

We invoke `reverse(first)`, and since `A` is not-null, we result in the following assignments:

```
in = A
next = B
```

We break the link between A and B at this step:

```
in.next = null;
```

So, we have:

```
first --> [A]  [B] -> null
```

Now we want the rest, which gets assigned to a recursive call of this function, with B instead.  We repeat the steps now with B, but since `B.next` is null, we're only left with B.

So, we get B back as the result of `rest`.  We now assign `next.next` to `in`, which means that `B.next` is now `A`.

```
[B] -> [A] -> null
        ^
      first
```

We return `rest` back to whomever called it, which in this case, results in the assignment to `first`.

```
first --> [B] -> [A] -> null
```

...and now, the list is reversed.

This is the general breakdown of it; take a look at it with three nodes and you'll see a bit more behavior.  Remember:  each recursive call creates new variables for `in` and `next`, and the ones that existed previously are set aside until we return from this particular method.

Comment: I guess my question at this point is, where does `rest.next` become `[A]` again? Or rather, if we are returning `rest`, how does `next`/`next.next` leave the scope of the method?